# HTML formatting tags being ignored in MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, formatting, newline

I've looked around and can't find a solution for this and it's driving me mad.

I've got a basic MVC2 app (C#) and am trying to display text from a database with the line breaks included. I've used the following:

```
<p><label>Description:</label>
<span class="fieldBlock"><%: Model.Description.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %></span>
</p>
```

This is adding the tags to the returned string as I'd expect but when the page renders it actually displays the tag as is instead of rendering the newline. ie. the text seen by the user in the browser is:

`"Quisque justo erat, iaculis sit amet aliquam eu, porttitor in mauris.<br /><br />Maecenas nisi velit, euismod at molestie vitae, malesuada id turpis. Mauris diam nisl, pretium id molestie nec, posuere posuere neque.<br /><br />Cras sed lectus nisl."`

This is the same in all major browsers so I'm obviously doing something foolish, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<%:` to `<%=`. This new notation encodes for HTML. The 2nd way is the old fashioned way.

Comment: Haha, good point! Cheers...I'm going to blame Monday morning for that.